# Mach Banding images in Android

Tags: android

I used a linear gradient image for a background and in Photoshop (and everything else) it looks nice and smooth but when I displayed it in the emulator is was banded!   What's worse, it's banded on my actual phone - a Droid Incredible.    I'm running 2.2 both in emulation and on the phone.

Here's a sample -  original on the left, Android'ed version on the right:  http://pnart.com/temp/AndroidMach.jpg

This has the appearance of Android imposing some bit-depth limitation.   What's going on and how do I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever find a satisfactory solution for this? I'm seeing the same issue and none of the solutions on SO appear to work.  The only solution I have so far is to add some noise to the image which appears to fix the banding, but it isn't ideal as the noise is visible.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and did some searching on Google. One of the sites I found suggested I put the gradient image in res/raw/ and load the image when needed. I tried this and it worked.

From what little I understand, any image you place under "drawable" will be processed by AAPT and it isn't guaranteed the final images will be the same as the ones you are putting into it. In this case, it decided to shrink the PNG gradient image to a smaller palette to shrink the size of the final APK. If someone else has a better (or more correct) explanation, I'd love to hear.

-Dan

Comment: I think the level of "optimisation" may vary by folder as I found moving an image with dreadful mach banding into the drawable-hdpi completely removed the problem on Google Nexus S.

This may not solve Peter's problem, as a comment from him below says he's tried this without any joy, but thought I would share this for other frustrated developers having similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

just try this: get down the width and height to the screen resolution of the device (eg: for moto droid: w:320px and h:480px and in photoshop keep the resolution to 200 dpi or above)

Regards,
Mistry Hardik

Comment: I want it to run on a variety of phones so the image I used was  900x500 (my Incredible is 800x480, the Droid X and Droid 2 are 854 x 480).     A background image needs to be able to display properly on a wide variety of resolutions.

Comment: m too tried the same earlier but to my surprise it didnt worked the way it should. so i tried to get the native resolution and then call in the view/background with a specific resolution. try doing something i requested and let me know the output.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it might be because it's scaling the image to fit the screen. When non-vector gradients are scaled they often get that "banded" look.  Try making a gradient that's the same size as the screen you're targeting, or try changing the ImageView (or whatever) that is displaying the image to make sure it's not stretching or scaling the image.

**EDIT**

In my opinion the best solution would be to create your gradient for your background at runtime have a look at [GradientDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html)

Comment: If you want an example of what I mean, and you're running Chrome (I'm not sure if this works in other browsers) bring up that example image you linked and hold control and mouse wheel in and out to zoom, you'll see it will give that gradient the banded look you were talking about.

Comment: I don't have Chrome but I do have Mozilla and IE and neither one of them band the image when zoomed or shrunk.      Interestingly, the Incredible itself, when I view the sample image on its web browser does band the left-hand (smooth) image while in the act of zooming but when I take my fingers off it's smooth again at any scale.

Comment: They do, they have to. Your graphics card will compensate a little, but if you have a rastered gradient, and you scale it at all, there will be some banding as it has no way to automatically say "hey, I know what's supposed to go between these two pixels when I stretch it". Now in Android it's probably more accentuated because of how it's processing the image or something. But I seriously would try making a gradient that matched the resolution of the screen.

Comment: I don't understand how this makes sense for Android development because it has to look good on a wide variety of devices.   Android developers don't have the luxury of predicting ahead of time what the screen resolution of their client will be.

Comment: BTW, I tried placing the image in different res subdirectories -  drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, and drawable-ldpi and it made no difference.

Comment: There isn't a computing device in the world this method would work with, Simply put, you can't scale one pre-rendered gradient image to look perfect on every screen, mobile device or 100" plasma. If you want it to look "perfect" you'll need to render the gradient from within your code. You'll need to programatically create a Bitmap that is the same width and height as the current screen, then to a gradient fill to it with a Canvas, then place that image in your ImageView or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the color depth of phone's screen is much worse than that of your PC. On your PC you have 8-8-8 bits depth for R-G-B but for phones it's typical to have 5-6-5 depth. It means that any fine gradients/shades that look good on PC will be distorted when displayed on the device because its color depth is just not enough, physically.

Therefore, designer's rule №1: **avoid fine shades and fine gradients in your designs**.

But if you *have to* then, of course, you may try the following, but you've been warned!

1) For runtime-generated gradients: use dithering, like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.screen_dashboard);
findViewById(R.id.layout).getBackground().setDither(true);
```

2) For graphics assets: always apply a 5-6-5 filter before saving png. Here is a **[good article](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=247)** with examples. Applying 5-6-5 filter ensures that color depth of your png is within device capabilities, and decreases png size too.

Comment: PS: You can get the Photoshop 5_6_5 plugin from the Telegraphics website: http://www.telegraphics.com.au/sw/.

Comment: I'm skeptical about this because the smooth (left) image in the link looks smooth in the default browser on the actual phone, regardless of how much I scale (pinch-zoom) it.   What's interesting is that WHILE I'm pinch-zooming it it gets the same banding, but when I take my fingers off the banding goes away.

Comment: @Peter: Well, I've told not _all_ truth - actually there is not only the phones display who's in charge, but also window's default color profile. The default for Android is 565, but it can be changed to 8888 (ARGB) programmatically. Here is a good link: http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2010/06/04/android-color-banding/ It may look to you better in the beginning. But there is a catch: very soon you'll start receiving OutOfMemory errors because with 8888 profile it required a _way_ more memory for bitmaps.

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't any special reason for using an image to get a gradient I highly recommend looking up the [Shape Drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) as it supports [gradients](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#gradient-element) which should (I haven't tried it but I assume) allow lossless scaling.